# Is it possible to get the IP addresses of all users who have joined a Teams meeting?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

I am building a Teams bot app and for one of the functions of the app, I need to check the IP address of the users who have joined that Teams meeting. Is there a way that Microsoft provides to get the IP addresses of the users who have joined a Teams meeting?
I tried raising this question in learn.microsoft but it looks like that the website is down. It is not allowing me to go through any of the threads there and gives me an error saying "learn.microsoft.com redirected you too many times." and clearing the cookies did not help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1388952/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ip-addresses-of-all-the

Answer (score 1):

From an API perspective (which it looks like you are trying to use) I do not think there is a Teams API that will return the user's IP address.

As you can see List Participants does not report this back:

List participants
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You can try suggesting this feautre:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472